Do I use "or" or "and" when specifying a list of three things, from which someone must choose two?
I'm writing some documentation for a software manual. A user must specify two (no more, no less) out of three options for a particular feature.
Which is correct: "You must specify two of A, B, or C." or "You must specify two of A, B, and C."? Or something else?

They're both OK, I think I usually see "or".

I'd use "You must specify two options out of options A, B, and C." You have "two out of three options" already in your question. The choice comes from the set of all 3, so and works better.

If this was a patent claim, lawyers would recommend finding a way to say "and" even when "or" might seem more natural.  In your example, I might try "You must specify exactly two from A, B, and C."

You must select exactly two of the three options.

"A user must specify two of the following (three) options..." I don't think there is a need to say exactly, since two is not one or three. It's clearly two and the app should only accept two anyway.

@Weather Vane 'Exactly' cuts out the oft-asked question 'Can I select just one?'

@EdwinAshworth if the app only accepts two it is unneccesary. Such explanation can make a user manual ponderous: ''First shalt thou take out the Holy Pin. Then shalt thou count to three, no more, no less. Three shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out. Once the number three, being the third number, be reached, then lobbest thou thy Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch towards thy foe, who, being naughty in My sight, shall snuff it."

@WV I was addressing the general question. App-specific requests are far better asked on sister sites.

@EdwinAshworth Actually, the difference between 'exactly two' and 'two' isn't the option to choose just one item (neither phrasing permits this), but the option to choose three items: after all, if one has chosen three items, it can be argued that one has also chosen two items plus a third item.

@ryang 'Choose two items' defaults to 'choose exactly two items' (pragmatics, the way people actually use the language, trumps logical concerns). But still people are apt to challenge instructions, and adding 'exactly' will pre-empt challenges rxcept for the most argumentative ones.

@EdwinAshworth there isn't a way to deal with people who, when advised to "pick two things" ask "can I pick one?" apart from a slap ;) You have to assume that the manual readers understand plain English. You can't cater for every stupid interpretation – it's not as if 'two' is ambiguous.

@EdwinAshworth Yes, and my comment was premised on what you just wrote. My point being that "select 2" precludes "select just 1" but does overlap with "select 3", and so the instruction "exactly 2" is to preempt the latter rather than the former.

To me,

"You must specify two of A, B, or C." or "You must specify two of A, B, and C."?

Both sound awkward. I would say "Choose any two from/of the options A, B and C."

From a viewpoint that is somewhat rigorous (formal, precise, careful, technical, …), the fragment

You must specify two of…

can be seen as a shortened version of the more complete

You must specify two elements from the set whose elements are…

On this view, the only acceptable answer to your question is “A, B, and C.”
Another paraphrase that would suggest the same conclusion is

You must specify two from among…

